# Nested Angular Material Menu

Tags: json, angular, menu, angular-material

I am new to angular and I'm creating a dynamic/nested menu based from my data below.  I include the codes that I started with.  Any help is appreciated.
Below is my json data:

```
dataList = [
{List: 'List 1', Client: 'Client A', Program: 'Client A Program 1'},
{List: 'List 2', Client: 'Client A', Program: 'Client A Program 1'},
{List: 'List 3', Client: 'Client A', Program: 'Client A Program 2'},    
{List: 'List 4', Client: 'Client A', Program: 'Client A Program 2'},
{List: 'List 5', Client: 'Client B', Program: 'Client B Program 1'},
{List: 'List 6', Client: 'Client B', Program: 'Client B Program 1'},
];
```

Here's what I've started so far:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of dataList>
       <div class="clientList">
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/home']" color="primary" (click)="menuClick()"><i class="fa object_group"
            aria-hidden="true"></i> {{item.Client}}</button>
      </div>      
    </ng-container>
```

I would like to have an angular material menu that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYIfR.jpg

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you show your code where you have a problem?

Comment: I'm a new to Angular.  I used static menu codes.

Comment: Anyway you have to at least start and then when you have some problems you ask specific questions. Not questions like "I have a task, do it for me"

Comment: I started something like this:  <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/home']" color="primary" (click)="menuClick()"><i class="fa object_group"
      aria-hidden="true"></i> Client A Program 1</button>
</div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Not all comments may be shown initially, or in order.

Comment: Thanks. Edited by adding codes